# Integrating Parse and Adobe Creative SDK in Android app

Tags: android, parse-platform, okhttp, adobecreativesdk

I am trying to integrate both Parse and Adobe Creative SDK in an Android app.
But whenever I am trying to launch the app, Parse.Initialize function throws an exception related to OKHTTP. Without the Creative SDK, the app runs fine.
How can I integrating both of them without breaking any of them?

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is correct , just make sure you add the following line to your build.gradle file

```
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.5.0'
```

Comment: [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33417118/how-to-integrate-creativesdkimage-with-an-exisiting-parse-android-project) for an explanation of what's going on here and why this fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You must be using okhttp 2.5 which in not supported by Adobe Creative SDK there are some removed java classes creating the issue.

Try to use okhttp 1.7 or prior.

Comment: Adobe Creative is the one working fine. It's Parse.initialize which is failing. 