# How to integrate CreativeSDKImage with an exisiting Parse Android Project?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, android-multidex, adobecreativesdk

The issue I have is that I have an existing project that depends on Parse. My question is how do I integrate Adobe CreativeSDKImage because it
extends MultiDexApplication whereas Parse Application (Class) extends Application.

Existing Project
e.g (MyApp extends Application ) import android.app.Application;

CreativeSDK based on [ADOBE CREATIVE SDK IMAGE GUIDE](https://creativesdk.adobe.com/docs/android/#/articles/gettingstarted/index.html)
e.g (CreativeSDKImageSampleApp extends) import android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication;

After hours of trying to figure out why my app now crashes everytime it starts-up, I noticed Parse.initilize is the issue or perhaps correct me if I'm wrong, as I also suspect extends MultiDexApplication might be the cause. I read limitations of using MultiDexApplication here for your reference; [BUILDING MULTIDEX](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html)

So please look at the code below to help me in the integration of Parse with CreativeSDKImage Application.

```js
package com.aviary.android.sample;

import android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication;
import com.aviary.android.feather.sdk.IAviaryClientCredentials;
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseACL;
import com.parse.ParseUser;

public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication implements IAviaryClientCredentials {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        // Enable Local Datastore.
        Parse.enableLocalDatastore(getApplicationContext());

        // Add your initialization code here
        Parse.initialize(this);

        ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
        ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
        // Optionally enable public read access.
        // defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
        ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
    }

    @Override
    public String getBillingKey() {
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    public String getClientID() {
        return "YOUR CLIENT ID";
    }

    @Override
    public String getClientSecret() {
        return "YOUR CLIENT SECRET";
    }
}
```

I am getting this error when I run the code;

```html
10-29 16:09:56.741 3700-3700/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-29 16:09:56.741 3700-3700/? E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.aviary.android.sample, PID: 3700
10-29 16:09:56.741 3700-3700/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method setFollowRedirects(Z)V in class Lcom/squareup/okhttp/OkHttpClient; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient' appears in /data/app/com.aviary.android.sample-1/base.apk)
10-29 16:09:56.741 3700-3700/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.parse.ParseOkHttpClient.<init>(ParseOkHttpClient.java:58)
10-29 16:09:56.741 3700-3700/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.parse.ParseHttpClient.createClient(ParseHttpClient.java:45)
10-29 16:09:56.741 3700-3700/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.parse.ParsePlugins$Android.newHttpClient(ParsePlugins.java:175)
10-29 16:09:56.741 3700-3700/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.parse.ParsePlugins.restClient(ParsePlugins.java:91)
10-29 16:09:56.741 3700-3700/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.parse.Parse.initialize(Parse.java:196)
10-29 16:09:56.741 3700-3700/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.parse.Parse.initialize(Parse.java:161)
10-29 16:09:56.741 3700-3700/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.aviary.android.sample.MyApplication.init(MyApplication.java:22)
10-29 16:09:56.741 3700-3700/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.aviary.android.sample.MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.java:14)
10-29 16:09:56.741 3700-3700/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1013)
10-29 16:09:56.741 3700-3700/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4707)
10-29 16:09:56.741 3700-3700/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
10-29 16:09:56.741 3700-3700/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405)
10-29 16:09:56.741 3700-3700/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-29 16:09:56.741 3700-3700/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
10-29 16:09:56.741 3700-3700/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
10-29 16:09:56.741 3700-3700/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-29 16:09:56.741 3700-3700/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
10-29 16:09:56.741 3700-3700/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
10-29 16:0
```

Build Gradle is below

```html
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

project(':external:calendar') {
    apply plugin: 'android-library'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 22
        buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

        sourceSets {
            main {
                manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
                java.srcDirs = ['src']
                resources.srcDirs = ['src']
                aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
                renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
                res.srcDirs = ['res']
                assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            }

        }

        lintOptions {
            abortOnError false
        }
    }
}

project(':external:colorpicker') {
    apply plugin: 'android-library'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 22
        buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

        sourceSets {
            main {
                manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
                java.srcDirs = ['src']
                resources.srcDirs = ['src']
                aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
                renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
                res.srcDirs = ['res']
                assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            }
        }
    }
}

project(':external:datetimepicker') {
    apply plugin: 'android-library'

    dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    }

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 22
        buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

        sourceSets {
            main {
                manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
                java.srcDirs = ['src']
                resources.srcDirs = ['src']
                aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
                renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
                res.srcDirs = ['res']
                assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            }
        }

        lintOptions {
            abortOnError false
        }
    }
}

project(':external:timezonepicker') {
    apply plugin: 'android-library'

    dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    }

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 22
        buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

        sourceSets {
            main {
                manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
                java.srcDirs = ['src']
                resources.srcDirs = ['src']
                aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
                renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
                res.srcDirs = ['res']
                assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            }
        }

        lintOptions {
            abortOnError false
        }
    }
}

project(':external:ex:chips') {
    apply plugin: 'android-library'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 22
        buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

        sourceSets {
            main {
                manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
                java.srcDirs = ['src']
                resources.srcDirs = ['src']
                aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
                renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
                res.srcDirs = ['res']
                assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            }
        }


        lintOptions {
            abortOnError false
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile project(':external:calendar')
    compile project(':external:colorpicker')
    compile project(':external:datetimepicker')
    compile project(':external:timezonepicker')
    compile project(':external:ex:chips')
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
    compile project(':ParseUI-Login')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src', 'external/ex/common/java']
            // NOTE: this includes external/ex/common/java!
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }

    /*
     * To sign release build, create file gradle.properties in ~/.gradle/ with this content:
     *
     * signingStoreLocation=/home/key.store
     * signingStorePassword=xxx
     * signingKeyAlias=alias
     * signingKeyPassword=xxx
     */
    if (project.hasProperty('signingStoreLocation') &&
            project.hasProperty('signingStorePassword') &&
            project.hasProperty('signingKeyAlias') &&
            project.hasProperty('signingKeyPassword')) {
        println "Found sign properties in gradle.properties! Signing build…"

        signingConfigs {
            release {
                storeFile file(signingStoreLocation)
                storePassword signingStorePassword
                keyAlias signingKeyAlias
                keyPassword signingKeyPassword
            }
        }

        buildTypes.release.signingConfig = signingConfigs.release
    } else {
        buildTypes.release.signingConfig = null
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add your build.gradle's `dependencies` block.

Comment: hi Alex Lipov, thanks for the response i've added the build.gradle to my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably because the aviary image component is using okhttp 1.6.0 while parse uses version 2.4.0 of the same library.
If you run `gradle :dependencies` on your project you will notice that only okhttp:1.6.0 is being linked.

If you updated your gradle dependencies, adding okhttp 2.*, it should work (just tested quickly though):

```
compile 'com.adobe.creativesdk:image:4.0.0'
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.2.1'
compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.10.3'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.5.0'
```